# Can't run docker container for a simple program

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile

I am planning to use docker for a c++ project.
I added a simple c++ program which prints 'hello world' to test it. 
Then I compiled it

```
g++ -o helloworldexecutable helloword.cpp
```

Added Dockerfile to projects root folder
Dockerfile includles:

```
FROM scratch
ADD helloworldexecutable / 
CMD helloworldexecutable
```

When I run: `sudo docker build --tag helloworldexecutable .` it shows that the build is successful. I see this image using `sudo docker images`
I can launch `sudo docker run hello-world` But running `sudo docker run helloexecutable` I get an error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The `helloworldexecutable` may not have execute permissions. Also don't you need `./` in front of executables as in `./helloworldexecutable`?

Comment: It does have execute permissions. And no you don't

Comment: It's dynamically linked, but a `FROM scratch` image doesn't contain any of the libraries or even the dynamic loader that you need to run it.

Comment: Also, if you say `CMD helloworldexecutable`, Docker tries to run `/bin/sh -c 'helloworldexecutable'`, and a `FROM scratch` image doesn't have a `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @DavidMaze While it doesn't *fix* the underlying issue, you should still add your comment as an answer, since it directly answers the question "why does this error occur?"

Answer (score 3):

Cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Compile (details about the `--static` flag follow):

```
g++ -o helloworldexecutable --static helloword.cpp
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD helloworldexecutable / 
CMD ["/helloworldexecutable"]
```

Outcome:

```
$ docker build -t testcpp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.254MB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2/3 : ADD helloworldexecutable /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0dd28bce4aed
Step 3/3 : CMD ["/helloworldexecutable"]
 ---> Running in 170a865b9527
Removing intermediate container 170a865b9527
 ---> 8a09e556c290
Successfully built 8a09e556c290
Successfully tagged testcpp:latest


$ docker container run --rm testcpp
Hello, World!$
```

---

From [Creating a Docker Image from Scratch](https://linuxhint.com/create_docker_image_from_scratch/):

> ### Creating a static binary
>
> ...But most high level applications depend on a lot of system libraries (like glibc, musl, klibc, etc) and a lot of runtime dependencies like Python or Node.js or Java Runtime. The application binary doesn’t have all the libraries available inside it, but when it starts execution it calls those libraries from the host operating system.
>
> Because we are trying to create an image from scratch, we would not be getting these niceties. So our application needs to be a static file or a standalone executable.